# Using BeautifulSoup4 to get a message from HTML

Tags: python

I have HTML like:

```
<a class="archive-title" target="_blank" href="http://python.jobbole.com/84100/" title="SQLAlchemy 和其他的 ORM 框架">SQLAlchemy 和其他的 ORM 框架</a><br />
            2016/01/12 &middot
```

I want to get the contents of href, title, and 2016/01/11.

I tried that with:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents)
result = soup.find_all("a", attrs={"class": "archive-title"})
for i in result:
    print i.get('href') + " " + i.get('title')
```

and the result is:

```
http://python.jobbole.com/84100/ SQLAlchemy 和其他的 ORM 框架
```

I do not know how to get the date 2016/01/11 at the same time.  What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried something already? Please show this (example code)! You did find BeautifulSoup as something that can help...

Comment: You could use result = soup.find_all(text=True). This will find all texts including the date (unfortunately, it will find the title again as well (also text)). Now you're looking in all 'a' tags, and the date is not in the <a></a> tag (but after it).

Answer (score 0):

If it is the same pattern in the whole page:

```
[a.parents.contents[-1] for a in soup.find_all('a')]
```

(change the index to other than -1 if there is more content in the parent node)

Answer (score 0):

Regex is always an option:

```
import re
src = """<a class="archive-title" target="_blank" href="http://python.jobbole.com/84100/" title="SQLAlchemy 和其他的 ORM 框架">SQLAlchemy 和其他的 ORM 框架</a><br />
        2016/01/12 &middot"""
print re.findall('(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2})', src.replace('\n','') )
```

The result is: ['2016/01/12']